# Docker start fails, named piped error

Tags: docker-compose, named-pipes

When i start docker on window, i often meet this error:

> ERRORERROR: Windows named pipe error: ・ｽw・ｽ閧ｳ・ｽ黷ｽ・ｽt・ｽ@・ｽC・ｽ・ｽ・ｽ・ｽ 
>   ｽ・ｽ・ｽﾂゑｿｽ・ｽ・ｽﾜゑｿｽ・ｽ・ｽB (code: 2)

Seem a lot of people experienced **Windows named pipe error** but nobody had met error like me :(
This can be resolved by command like

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

but it took me a lot of time.

Does anybody have solution? Thank you!
(I'm using window 7)

Comment: Do you meet the error again after running ```docker-machine create -d virtualbox default```?

Comment: Yes, always, after 2 or 3 days. So i need to find another solution.

Comment: You have to make sure your  ```C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker``` folder won't be changed by other programs.